# Using .find() to target muliple class to store current class as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

UPDATE: how can I find 1 of a possible 4 classes and store that active class into a variable

Logically I was thinking

`var current = $('.footerUl').find('.blue .white .pink .green');`

Only one of these classes will be active at a time ( thought jquery would toss out the rest) but this doesn't work.  How can look for muli-classes to test which one is currently active and store that into a variable for future use.

```
    <footer id="footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class="footerUl">
      <li id="worksFooterNavi" class="navi"><a href="#">works</a></li>
      <li id="aboutFooterNavi" class="navi"><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li class="homeFooterNavi navi currentFooterNav white"><a href="#" title="logo">
        <div class="logo activeFooter">

        </div>
        </a> ​
      </li>
      <li id="contactFooterNavi"  class="navi"><a href="#">contact</a></li>
      <li id="followFooterNavi"  class="navi"><a href="#">follow</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
</div>
```

This isnt limited to only `.find()` this is just my terrible hack and slash method of doing jquery.

Comment: And how do you define "active" item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your point but this line has an incorrect syntax

```
var current = $('.footerUl').find('.blue .white .pink .green');
```

replace it by

```
var current = $('.footerUl').find('.blue, .white, .pink, .green');
```

And these 2 line will help you to get the actual class

```
regex = /blue|white|pink|green/;
var cssClass = current.prop('class').match(regex);
```

Comment: Will this match elements with any one of those classes, or elements with ***all*** those classes?

Comment: since only of of the 4 classes will be in the html I want to find one of them and then save that attr class into var current

Comment: must i use .attr()? somehow to get it saved into current?

Comment: Also, @Matthew Harwood, this code won't store the active class as a string; it'll store the node that matches as a jQuery object in your `current` variable. You'll have to do `currentClass = current.attr('class')` to get that.

Comment: could you expand on that as a full question so i can mark it correct?

Comment: @Matthew Hardwood I think Claudio answered the lion's share of your question - mark his as correct and I'll put it through as an edit. That ok?

Comment: Regex is slight overkill here Claudio, no?

Comment: @JasperMogg: any of those 4 classes can be the active one so I thought it will be the shortest and clearest way, the other option is an `if` for each valid class to see which one is present. Do you see other option?

Comment: `var currentClass = $('.footerUl').find('.blue, .white, .pink, .green').attr('class')`

Comment: accually that returns al the other classes too jasper

Comment: @Jasper Mogg: but that would give you for the active one (in the sample html) `homeFooterNavi navi currentFooterNav white`. I understand he only wants to get `.blue, .white, .pink, .green`. I could be wrong though

Comment: but I cannot get claudio's script to do anything

Comment: @MatthewHarwood: check this demo to see if it's what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/uuUqg/

Comment: duh I was forgetting my orginal find()  @ClaudioRedi any idea why the alert says white,white twice?